# Use a different twig media template if it is being rendered inside a WYIWYG

Tags: media, 9

I have a twig template for a media entity that I wish to be able to embed into a WYIWYG. I am able to, however the entity has issues rendering when inside the ckeditor that aren't present when rendered on an actual page. I want to either use a different template or use some variable that detects whether the media is in an edit mode.

Is there a twig variable like
{{ inEditor }} or is there a template I could use specific to wyiwygs like
media--remote-video--WYIWYG.html.twig ?

When viewing the element in a preprocess function I do see there is a 'view_mode' variable but that's always set to default.

Comment: May be easier to allow someone to select the view mode of the media being inserted, then you can provide a twig file for each one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check for the route name `media.filter.preview`:

```
if (\Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName() === 'media.filter.preview') {
  // media is rendered inside CKEditor
  $variables['inEditor'] = TRUE;
}
// add cache context
$variables['#cache']['contexts'][] = 'route.name';
```

Comment: Which preprocess hook could I use this in?

Comment: hook_preprocess_media()